# Scala in intellij cannot find my function definition?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I implemented a toy worksheet in intellij.

```
abstract class Nat:
  def isZero: Boolean
  def predecessor: Nat
  def successor: Nat
  def + (that: Nat): Nat
  def - (that: Nat): Nat
end Nat

object Zero extends Nat:
  def isZero: Boolean = true
  def predecessor: Nat = ???
  def successor: Nat = Succ(this)
  def + (that: Nat): Nat = that
  def - (that: Nat): Nat = if that.isZero then this else ???
  override def toString = "Zero"
end Zero

class Succ(n: Nat) extends Nat:
  def isZero: Boolean = false
  def predecessor: Nat = n
  def successor: Nat = Succ(this)
  def + (that: Nat): Nat = Succ(n + that)
  def - (that: Nat): Nat = if that.isZero then this else n - that.predecessor
  override def toString = s"Succ($n)"
end Succ

val two = Succ(Succ(Zero)) // : Succ =
val one = Succ(Zero)
two + one
two - one
//one - two
```

Other worksheet has been evaluated fine so far, but when I evaluated this one, I encountered some errors show below:

```
// defined class Nat







4 |  def successor: Nat = Succ(this)
  |                       ^^^^
  |                       Not found: Succ






// defined class Succ








1 |val two = Succ(Succ(Zero))
  |                    ^^^^
  |                    Not found: Zero
1 |val one = Succ(Zero)
  |               ^^^^
  |               Not found: Zero
1 |two + one
  |^^^
  |Not found: two
1 |two - one
  |^^^
  |Not found: two
```

How to resolve the not found error?

Comment: Worksheets are evaluated line by line and at that line, `Succ` doesn't exist. The best you can do is write that code in a normal project and then import those classes in a worksheet or just use the main method.

Comment: Or wrap everything in a single object

Comment: Try this: Bring up the **Worksheet Settings** (click on the little wrench icon, upper left) and change the **Run type:** from REPL to Plain. See if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The specific problem is that worksheets are executed in order and `Succ` has not been defined when `Zero` is being defined.

More generally I suggest switching to a full `App` rather than a worksheet. Writing and running an `App` is pretty east. Create a subclass of `App` with your code:

```
object Worksheet extends App {
  println("Hello world")
}
```

Then just click the green arrow to the left of the `object` and IntelliJ will compile and run the program.

[image]

Or right click and select Debug so that you can put breakpoints on key points the code and then step through line by line.